# How to handle optional struct parameters when calling C functions from C#

Tags: c#, c, winscard

How can i skip the optional parameter (pioRecvPci) in C#?
I think the main problem is that in C the parameter is a pointer so it is possible to supply NULL while in C# the ref keyword on a struct is used which can't be null by definition.

**C Code**

```
typedef struct {
  DWORD dwProtocol;
  DWORD cbPciLength;
} SCARD_IO_REQUEST;

LONG WINAPI SCardTransmit(
      __in         SCARDHANDLE hCard,
      __in         LPCSCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendPci,
      __in         LPCBYTE pbSendBuffer,
      __in         DWORD cbSendLength,
      __inout_opt  LPSCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvPci,
      __out        LPBYTE pbRecvBuffer,
      __inout      LPDWORD pcbRecvLength
    );
```

**C# Code**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SCARD_IO_REQUEST
{
    public int dwProtocol;
    public int cbPciLength;
}

[DllImport("winscard.dll")]
public static extern int SCardTransmit(
     int hCard, 
     ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest, 
     ref byte SendBuff, 
     int SendBuffLen, 
     ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest, 
     ref byte RecvBuff, 
     ref int RecvBuffLen);
```

Comment: You could use a `class` instead (I vaguely remember using this approach successfully a long, long time ago). Alternatively, it might work to declare the parameters as `SCARD_IO_REQUEST?`, but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `struct` to a `class` and then pass `null`. Remember that a C# `struct` is quite different from a C++ `struct`, and here your really want to use a C# `class`.

Or if you always want to ignore `pioRecvRequest` change the signature of `SCardTransmit` so that `pioRecvRequest` is of type `IntPtr`. Then pass `IntPtr.Zero` for the value.

Actually, the `SCARD_IO_REQUEST` is just a header and if you want to pass it in the call you will have to manage this structure and the additional buffer space yourself anyway so `IntPtr` is the right choice. You will then have to use the `Marshal` functions to allocate and fill the structure before the call and unmarshal the data and free it after the call.

Answer (score 3):

C# supports method overloads.  Something you can take advantage of here, redeclare the method but now give it an IntPtr argument type (no ref).  And pass IntPtr.Zero.

Second way is to marshal the structure yourself.  Declare the argument type IntPtr.  And use Marshal.AllocHGlobal() to allocate memory for the structure, Marshal.StructureToPtr() to copy the structure into it.  Marshal.FreeHGlobal() after the call.  Or pass IntPtr.Zero.  Clearly the overload trick is much less painful.